# Using sed to filter output of rsync --itemize-changes -i

Tags: sed, regular-expression

After using `rsync --itemize-changes -i --recursive --checksum --dry-run` to compare the contents of two drives, I got this kind of result:

```
2024/03/12 08:31:01 [15248] .d          Backups/Phone/Pictures/Screenshots/
2024/03/12 08:31:01 [15248] .f          Backups/Phone/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20190726-175033.png
2024/03/12 08:15:12 [15248] cd+++++++++ Backups/User profile/user/.mozilla/firefox/fk3vbf2j.Old profile/storage/default/https+++www.example.org/ls/
2024/03/12 08:15:12 [15248] cf+++++++++ Backups/User profile/user/.mozilla/firefox/fk3vbf2j.Old profile/storage/default/https+++www.example.org/ls/index.html
```

I'd like to filter out the non modified files and folders (the ones with `.d` and `.f`) with sed since the file was too big for a file editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed  '/[0-9\/]* [0-9:]* [[0-9]*] \.[fd]*[[:space:]]*.*/d' source_file > result_file
```

The result:

```
2024/03/12 08:15:12 [15248] cd+++++++++ Backups/User profile/user/.mozilla/firefox/fk3vbf2j.Old profile/storage/default/https+++www.example.org/ls/
2024/03/12 08:15:12 [15248] cf+++++++++ Backups/User profile/user/.mozilla/firefox/fk3vbf2j.Old profile/storage/default/https+++www.example.org/ls/index.html
```

I managed to make the regex thanks to these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65701256/1223073
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468704/regex101-vs-sed#comment101414929_57468704
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468704/regex101-vs-sed#comment101417314_57468704